# I'm failing to create a canvas

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I write this code:

```
import turtle 
t=turtle.pen()
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: what is error in this code ? please mentioned your confused point

Answer (score 0):

Given what little code you've supplied, I'm guessing you're already in trouble because of this line:

```
t=turtle.pen()
```

What you most likely want is:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
```

Letter case matters as the lowercase `pen()` function returns a list of attributes about the (default) pen whereas the uppercase `Pen()` function creates a new pen (turtle) that you can manipulate.

Python is a case sensitive language, so this is why that matters.